Reorg on Optimism/Base
I was looking into the Optimism derivation spec and saw that it mentioned there are possibilities that Optimism/Base block can be reorged. One of them is due to consolidation failure.
According to this section: https://specs.optimism.io/protocol/derivation.html#l1-consolidation-payload-attributes-matching, it mentioned:
If consolidation fails, .....
The payload attributes are chosen in favor of the previous unsafe L2 block, creating an L2 chain reorg on top of the current safe block

I thought every op-node inside this network are verifiers, except for the sequencer which has sequence mode enabled.
So my questions are

How does the verifier trigger such reorg to all other nodes after it finds out that consolidation failed?
And how does it notifies the Sequencer about such reorg?

Thanks!

According to the discussion thread here, I think I've found the answer to this.

The sequencer doesn't actively do anything to trigger a reorg if the batch data on L1 doesn't match the unsafe chain - the derivation process each node runs just prefers following L1 batch data to what the sequencer publishes so once they process the conflicting L1 data they will automatically reorg to that chain which invalidates the unsafe blocks. Since the sequencer's derivation pipeline will perform the same reorg, the sequencer will wind up building a new set of unsafe blocks on top of the new safe head. So not at all like the DAO fork - just a regular application of the fork choice rules of the protocol.

source: https://github.com/ethereum-optimism/developers/discussions/510#discussioncomment-9981674
